# cocos2dx android app doesn't lock the screen after inactivity

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I ported my Cocos2dx game from iOS to Android. Everything works fine, but there is something strange on lock screen on android. The application doesn't lock the screen after inactivity.
I try to change SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT programmatically from my app. It changes, but not to my application.
I found on stackoverflow tips on calculating idle time, and then lock the screen programmatically. Is the only way? Is the screen should not be blocked automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try to call method setKeepScreenOn(false) in your cocos2d-x activity, which call method in Cocos2dxActivity.java This will allow game to sleep. After some time, if you have screen lock set in your phone settings will lock the screen.

> setKeepScreenOn(true) function that prevent phone to sleep, useful for some
>   games

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's strange, but it not work for me. I define Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView mGLView in AppActivity.java, and then in onCreate( ) I set mGLView.setKeepScreenOn(false). Application runs without warnings, but doesn't sleep. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's my fail. I left getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) in onResume( ). Now everything works fine!